# Facebook custom story layout

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Does anyone know which attribute on the facebook open graph custom story controls the section highlighted in this picture?
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxYOAz86zlLvSEN5bFlUUWV6bm8/edit

I looked at the docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/

and it mentions editing the attachment but I can't find the property that would be responsible for that specific highlighted content

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

it the message attribute of the story.

for example in the php sdk:

```
 $response = $facebook->api(
   'me/namespace:action',
   'POST',
   array(
     'object' => id of object or json with all object params,
     'message' => here is the message
   )
 );
```

be carefull though, facebook will not validate your app if it is not the final client (facebook user) that ads the text there. you cannot pre fill it no more.